# Writing a function to compute execution time in both Node and browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to write a clean function that is supported by both Node and the browser, but feel that the cleanliness of the solution is not as good as it could be.

Would it be hacky to have conditionals checking the presence of the window object?

```
if (typeof window !== undefined)
    // node computation
else 
    // browser computation
```

But I also want a clean way to compute the total execution time before and after some operation. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `performance` API is specified by a [W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/#sec-performance) and available in both Node and browsers.

- [Node Performance Timing API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_class_performance)
- [Performance Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Performance)

In Node you would need to include `perf_hooks`.

Already with just `performance.now()` you can do basic timing operations:

```js
// Detect existance of `performance`. If not defined (Node), require it
var performance = performance || require('perf_hooks').performance;

let start = performance.now();

let j = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) j = j*2+1;

console.log((performance.now() - start).toFixed(2) + "ms");
```

The same code runs on Node at [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/PerformanceNode).

Comment: Do I need to conditionally use this based on Node or browser in the code? I'm seeing Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' and I'm requiring performance in from that module.

Comment: Indeed, you need to conditionally require perf_hook. The condition is whether you have `performance` defined or not yet. I update my answer, including a link to repl.it where you can see the same code run on Node.

Comment: I'm still getting "Error: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' " for some reason, even though it's a native node module. Any reason for this? I'm using webpack

Comment: What's your Node version?

Comment: 10.15 is the version using node -v

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't work, as it works [in a standard Node box](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/PerformanceNode). As I see it, you are now struggling with a different problem. If you cannot get it solved, I suggest asking a new question, providing enough details (web pack, etc), so we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Sure thing, I agree. I've posted an additional question. Thanks for the help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59616541/node-unable-to-find-perf-hooks-modules