# Node unable to find perf_hooks modules

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use perf_hooks for the `performance` API in node.

`const { performance } = require('perf_hooks')`

However, I keep getting `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks`. I ran `node -v` and see `10.15`

Comment: Is it just me or is there no code in that package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/perf_hooks -> https://github.com/mcollina/perf_hooks

Comment: It's native to Node, not an npm module

Comment: I tried it on 10.15.0 and 10.15.3 it works on both of the versions. I do not understand what the issue might be in your case.

Comment: I have the same error, `v12.13.1`

Comment: i get the same error in Meteor's (1.9.2) legacy build

Comment: same for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64752215/why-requireperf-hooks-fails