# Why require("perf_hooks") fails?

Tags: javascript, npm, chromium, benchmarking

In my understanding "perf_hooks" is a part of Node.js. However when testing with `npm test` it fails for me with the following (some filenames are changed):

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'perf_hooks'
      at Object.openSync (fs.js:465:3)
      at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:368:35)
      at SandboxedModule._getCompileInfo (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:265:20)
      at SandboxedModule._compile (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:245:22)
      at createInnerSandboxedModule (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:183:23)
      at SandboxedModule.RecursiveRequireProxy (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:214:27)
      at /Users/asmirnov/Documents/blabla2.js:51:12
      at Object.<anonymous> (lib/profiler.js:53:3)
      at SandboxedModule._compile (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:251:19)
      at createInnerSandboxedModule (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:183:23)
      at SandboxedModule.RecursiveRequireProxy (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:214:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (lib/blabla1.js:29:20)
      at SandboxedModule._compile (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:251:19)
      at createInnerSandboxedModule (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:183:23)
      at SandboxedModule.RecursiveRequireProxy (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:214:27)
      at SandboxedModule.requireInterceptor (node_modules/sandboxed-module/lib/sandboxed_module.js:227:9)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/blabla1.js:73:22)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)
```

This is a part of the file (`lib/profiler.js`) that uses it:

```
const {performance, PerformanceObserver} = (function()
{
  try
  {
    if (window && typeof window.performance == "undefined")
      throw new TypeError();
    return window;
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    return require("perf_hooks");
  }
})();
```

What can be a reason? However in some scenarios (`npm run ..`) it works as expected. Any suggestions are appreciated.

PS. Node is relatively fresh:

```
> node --version
v14.8.0
```

Comment: This is strange, [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) says it should be located in `lib/perf_hooks.js` but in my install this file is missing too

Comment: `perf_hooks` is indeed in that version of Node.js. In 14.8.0, `require()` throws `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` (and not `ENOENT`) when it can't find a module, so the problem is something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "sandboxed-module" 2.0.3 issue that was fixed in 2.0.4.

Comment: Nice! FWIW, based on https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module/commit/a0385f74f6dabd9169cbbe9f70bb3ab20270d367, I would think the bug is in 2.0.0 and fixed in 2.0.1 and later. But whatever, I'm splitting hairs and could be wrong anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`perf_hooks` is indeed in that version of Node.js. In 14.8.0, `require()` throws `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` (and not `ENOENT`) when it can't find a module, so the problem is something else.

If it is definitely the `require()` line that is throwing, then it seems likely that `require()` has been monkey-patched. If they patched `require()` but not `module.require()`, you can try changing `require()` to `module.require()` in `lib/profiler.js`.

EDIT: As OP suggests, `sandboxed-module` is a likely culprit since it messes with module loading. They report that it's fixed in 2.0.4, but based on [the repository information on the fix](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module/commit/a0385f74f6dabd9169cbbe9f70bb3ab20270d367), it would appear to be fixed in 2.0.1. Either way, updating to 2.0.4 (or later, but that's the latest as of this writing) is .

Comment: module.require() did not help unfortutantly. If i create "lib/perf_hooks.js" it's automatically picked up, otherwise node's one is just not found. Any possible "SandboxedModule" issue?

Comment: > They report that it's fixed in 2.0.4. That's actually me who reports that it solved the issue. I looked into what was changed (3 commits) and did not get how it fixed it frankly. So it can happen that's it's related to smth else but it actually worked for me. Let me know if you can explain why it helped.